# ArrayList.add(idx,element) corrupt other element of array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, corruption

I'm running a program that:

1. Create an `ArrayList`
2. Add some element on the top of this array
3. Create a "base" element which will be decreased
4. Then with a for loop decrease the base element and add it on the top of the array (index 0)
5. **Unexpectedly the output that I get is terrifying**

Please don't feel bad about some italian word:

- "ora" means hour, so

  ```
  Ora hour = new Ora(6,34) //--> 6:34
  ```
- "decrementaMinuti" decrease minutes from the hour

This is the full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Ora> hours = new ArrayList<>();

    hours.add(0, new Ora(01,00));
    hours.add(0, new Ora(00,00));

    Ora base = hours.get(0);
    System.out.println("Base: " + base + "\n");        

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        System.out.println("First: " + base);
        // decreasing 60 minutes from hour
        base.decrementaMinuti(60);

        System.out.println("After: " + base);
        hours.add(0, base);

        System.out.println("In Array: " + hours.get(0));

        System.out.println("[hours]");
        for (int j = 0; j < hours.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println("[" + hours.get(j) + "]");
        }

        System.out.println("- - - - - - - -\n");
    }

}
```

And this is the output I got:

```
Base: 11:00

First: 11:00
After: 10:00
In Array: 10:00
[hours]
[10:00]
[10:00]
[12:00]
- - - - - - - -

First: 10:00
After: 09:00
In Array: 09:00
[hours]
[09:00]
[09:00]
[09:00]
[12:00]
- - - - - - - -

First: 09:00
After: 08:00
In Array: 08:00
[hours]
[08:00]
[08:00]
[08:00]
[08:00]
[12:00]
- - - - - - - -

First: 08:00
After: 07:00
In Array: 07:00
[hours]
[07:00]
[07:00]
[07:00]
[07:00]
[07:00]
[12:00]
- - - - - - - -
```

In the last block of output there are the hour `7:00` 5 times when I never add the same hour two times.

**I'm asking**: why (as you can see) adding an element of the top of this array cause that also the after elements were corrupted?

My java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Any help you can procide is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the same instance multiple times to the List :

```
Ora base = hours.get(0); // this is the instance added multiple times
System.out.println("Base: " + base + "\n");        

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    System.out.println("First: " + base);
    // decreasing 60 minutes from hour
    base.decrementaMinuti(60);

    System.out.println("After: " + base);
    hours.add(0, base); // here you add the same instance multiple times
```

You must create a new `Ora` instance before adding it to the List:

```
Ora base = hours.get(0);
System.out.println("Base: " + base + "\n");        

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    System.out.println("First: " + base);
    Ora newOra = new Ora (...); // consider having a copy constructor that
                                // would accept base and copy its data
    // add code to update newOra to contain the same data as base

    // decreasing 60 minutes from hour
    newOra.decrementaMinuti(60);

    System.out.println("After: " + newOra);
    hours.add(0, newOra); // add the new instance
```

Answer (score 3):

You are adding the same object, `Ora base = hours.get(0)` and you just changing the content of the object. However is the same reference. ArrayList allows you to add the same object reference multiple times, but entries in the ArrayList are actually referring to the same object, and the same memory area with data. That is why all are printing the same result.

Comment: Accepted for the better explanation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's because when you do : "Ora base = hours.get(0);" 
base is not a copy of the variable. Java is always pointer in fact.

hours.add(0, base); will result in adding the same one, two or three time.

Comment: Misleading answer, java is strictly pass by value not pass by reference (or pointer).  However, the value which gets passed is the value on the stack, which for objects is a reference to a memory address in the object heap.